# Why do some user accounts import without email address?

Tags: 2013, sync, ups

I have a AD UPS sync Setup within SharePoint 2013. The mail to `workemail` mapping is correct, and the majority of users import with all attributes including email address - However a range of users import without an email address, which definitely exists within AD. All users are within the same AD container.

I cannot find any discrepancies in accounts for those users who do and don't have emails post-UPS sync.

Do you have any suggestions on a possible cause or items to investigate please?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is might be with the properties of those users.

1. Launch ADSI Edit
2. Browse the directory and find the user account which has the issue
3. Open the properties
4. Check the mail attribute and make sure it has value

Now open up SharePoint user profile properties and make sure the email property in SharePoint is mapped to the correct property in AD

Do a full synchronization.